# Canny and Sobel in Stroke Width transform

Tags: image-processing

There is two edge detection methods use in Stroke width transform. Why Canny and Sobel is used in (SWT) Stroke Width transform?

Comment: Other question: why not ?

Comment: I am now studying stoke width transform. I don't now why canny and sobel use in SWT.If you don't mind, could you explain me more details?

Comment: What do you understand of SWT ?